# How to lay 2 images side by side in html?

Tags: html, css

This is my current code:

```
<figure class="half">
    <img style="width:400px" src="http://alexmarshall12.github.io/assets/img/colored_1693146.png">
    <img style="width:600px" src="http://alexmarshall12.github.io/assets/img/one-piece-1693146_colored2.png">
    <figcaption>Caption describing these two images.</figcaption>
</figure>
```

Unfortunately perhaps because the images are too wide, it still puts the second image on the next line. I want to avoid this - no matter how wide things get. How can I do this?

Comment: Just put two images in two divisions and put that two divisions in one main division. use float: left to put it side by side

Comment: If you want images, side by side, on every possible screen size, you could do something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/zvv38vup/1/ Anyway, i would rather use media queries for lower screens resolutions, and place one above another (for lower screen sizes)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just add css `display:flex` to parent container of images in your case figure.

```html
<figure class="half" style="display:flex">
    <img style="width:400px" src="http://alexmarshall12.github.io/assets/img/colored_1693146.png">
    <img style="width:600px" src="http://alexmarshall12.github.io/assets/img/one-piece-1693146_colored2.png">
    <figcaption>Caption describing these two images.</figcaption>
</figure>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could put your images into table cells.

```html
<figure class="half">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <img style="width:400px;" src="http://alexmarshall12.github.io/assets/img/colored_1693146.png">
      </td>
      <td>
        <img style="width:600px;" src="http://alexmarshall12.github.io/assets/img/one-piece-1693146_colored2.png">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <figcaption>Caption describing these two images.</figcaption>
</figure>
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend just using a `<span>` tag and put no space in between them, then they will be side by side.

Answer (score 0):

This could be achieved in many ways. 
You could use flexbox
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

You could wrap it grid system and set image width to 100% or create table and set width of each td to be 50%

You can even set css for all of your images to be exactly the same size.

Answer (score 0):

I've created a little fiddle for you https://jsfiddle.net/7kophdxq/.

I would strongly recommend using flexbox, since its the 'new way' of doing these kind of things. Of course you could use a table, but it isn't tabular data right?

For the general structure:

```
<div class="columns">
  <div class="columns__item"></div>
  <div class="columns__item"></div>
</div>
```

Each `columns__item` has a width of 50%. Inside each `columns__item` I've put a little image (and made sure it will not exceed a width of 100% of its container):

```
<figure>
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/400/" />
  <figcaption>Image caption</figcaption>
 </figure>
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
.half img {
   display:inline-block;
}
.half figcaption {
  display:block
}
```

or, if you want to keep images in one line, regardless the container size:

```
.half {
   white-space:nowrap;
}
.half img {
   display:inline;
}
.half figcaption {
  display:block
}
```

Pick whatever suits you best;)