# horizontal align two images

Tags: html, css

[enter image description here][1]On my website, I'm planning to put two images but I can't vertically align them.
I tried `line-height` and vertical alignment. but I can't figure out where I went wrong or what codes I'm lacking.

```css
.logo img {
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 3px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.logo2 img {
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 3px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <nav>
    <a href="guest_login.php" class="logo">
      <img src="images/guesticon.png">
      <h2 class="name">GUEST</h2>
    </a>

    <a href="officer_login.php" class="logo2">
      <img src="images/policeicon.png">
      <h2 class="name">ADMIN</h2>
    </a>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/04bup35k/

this is the output i want to achieve
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9cpk8.png

Comment: Please add more details to it. In would aspect are you trying to vertically align them? The height of the parent element is calculated to fit-content. naturally you cant vertically align an item inside a container that has not a hight higher then the content.

Comment: Add image/draft of the final output you want to achieve.

Comment: @Newbee im sorry if im lacked in details, i re-edit my post  about the output i want to achieve

Comment: Use a flex-box.

Comment: Is it vertical align? or horizontal align? the output image is beside each other(horizontal) but in your question *"you can't vertically align them"*?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to lay 2 images side by side in html?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41174458/how-to-lay-2-images-side-by-side-in-html)

Comment: @Newbee i mean horizontal sorry for the mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To ***horizontally*** align the two images you can use `display: flex;` on `nav`.

```css
.logo img {
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 3px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.logo2 img {
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 3px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.logo,
.logo2 {
 text-align: center;
}


nav {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <nav>
    <a href="guest_login.php" class="logo">
      <img src="images/guesticon.png">
      <h2 class="name">GUEST</h2>
    </a>

    <a href="officer_login.php" class="logo2">
      <img src="images/policeicon.png">
      <h2 class="name">ADMIN</h2>
    </a>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.logo-container {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    /* add any other styles you need */
}
```

```html
<a href="guest_login.php" class="logo">
  <div class="logo-container">
    <img src="images/guesticon.png">
    <h2 class="name">GUEST</h2>
  </div>
</a>

<a href="officer_login.php" class="logo2">
  <div class="logo-container">
    <img src="images/policeicon.png">
    <h2 class="name">ADMIN</h2>
  </div>
</a>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

As [@tacoshy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14072420/tacoshy) suggests, you should elaborate your problem. What do you mean by aligning them vertically?

**EDIT:**
Hmm, seems like [@Kameron](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16496357/kameron) robbed my bounties by giving an legitimate answer. I also upvote his answer.

**Old answer:**
Well, I'm assuming that you were trying to align them in `x` direction. The behaviour you're expecting can't achieved by using `vertical-align`. Instead, you can use CSS layouts such as, [CSS Flexbox](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp) or [Grid](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_grid.asp) to achieve this. I'm gonna use Flexbox for this, because it's flexible to use.

First of all, you have to make the parent of those **images** `flex`. Like this:

```css
nav {
  display: flex;
}
```

Both of the images should've been aligned vertically by now.

**BONUS:**

You are not following the best practices of making a navigation. **First**, make an unordered list (`ul`) and put two list (`li`) inside of it. Now put hyperlinks inside of each list element. Give each list element a `logo` class.

```html
<div class="main">
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li class="logo">
        <a href="guest_login.php">
          <img src="images/guesticon.png" />
          <h2 class="name">GUEST</h2>
        </a>
      </li>

      <li class="logo">
        <a href="officer_login.php">
          <img src="images/policeicon.png" />
          <h2 class="name">ADMIN</h2>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

**Secondly**, in CSS, you can also reduce some redundant lines of code. Notice that you have the same styles applied to both of the images repeatedly. You can minimize it by grabbing the selector of both and apply styles for once. For example:

```css
/* This line following styles will make images align vertically. */
nav ul {
  display: flex;
  height: 150px;
}

.logo {
  flex: 1; /* To give them equal amount of free space */
  margin: 20px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding: 3px;
}

.logo img {
  width: 150px;
}
```

**Thirdly**, you may want to align heading. You can achieve this by simply adding `text-align: center` in your heading's style. For example:

```css
.name {
  text-align: cetner;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

Would this be what you are looking for?

```
.logo img {
   height: 150px;
   width: 150px;
   margin: 20px;
   padding: 3px;
   margin-top: 10px;
   vertical-align: middle;
  }

.logo2 img{
   height: 150px;
   width: 150px;
   margin: 20px;
   padding: 3px;
   margin-top: 10px;
   vertical-align: middle;
}

.logo {
  display: inline-block;
}

.logo2 {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: this does not vertically align images. Beyond that, it is poorly coded it is repetitive as both logos and images within the logos have the very same property and values. They should be combined then. However, they question changed according to the comments. It is not about vertical alignment in the first place.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).